# How to check if an argument is a string in unix

Tags: unix, scripting, hp-ux

I am calling a script with argument as "incr":

```
script.sh incr
```

I need to check if the argument passed is "incr" or not.

Also, "incr" can be any argument,not necessarily the first.
For ex :

```
script.sh -l incr
```

Any general way to check if any argument is "incr" or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if a particular argument is a string, the answer is "yes".  All arguments are strings.  If you want to know if an argument is a particular string, check it:

```
for arg; do
  if test "$arg" = incr; then
    echo incr is passed as an argument
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Could you please modify the code so that it becomes like :
If(any particular argument is "incr")
then
do something
fi

Comment: @6190 Sure, but you can modify it, too!